# Save Json into sqlite and compare with old data when everytime call API

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm trying to save Json data into sqlite,

And everytime when I open my app,

I need to call the json API and get the new json data.

If there is something different with the old data in sqlite, update it.

I've already save the json data into sqlite,

but I'm not sure whether there is a way to compare the old data with the new data?

Comment: You should split your JSON into logical columns and save it in normal SQLite table(s). Then all kinds of data manipulations would be so much easier, as well as performance will be good even with large number of rows if you create proper indexes

Comment: Are you saving the whole JSON string in a single column in the SQLite db?

Comment: No,I save the data in table and create attribute like id,name,type to save the json object